# How can I consolidate mysql insert?

Tags: c#, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do.
I have a grails service which is launched, using a socket, with a command on a service running on a windows machine written in C#.

This service, to make it easy, just writes a record to a MySQL database, using a transaction and finishing with a MySQL `commit` to be sure to have committed everything.

It works fine, the problem is that after this, I launch in the grails side another service, which should find the new record just inserted with a simple `FindBy`. But it doesn't find anything. If I run it a second time then it works good.

It seems that for the grails side it takes time to see this record, so I was wondering if there is a way before starting this second service to flush the DB in some way to be sure to be in a consistent situation.

Comment: Hi guys, at the end I forced a refresh on the single domain class, something like. def tmp=ExampleData.get(1); tmp.refresh()